# What is the meaning of assigning a number (not a character) to a char variable?

Tags: c, char

```
char a =2;    **without quotes**. WHAT is the meaning of this statement
```

since
    char a='2';    means the ASCII  value of 2 stores in a  but what about without quotes

Comment: Look e.g. here for what 2 encodes in ASCII: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_code_chart

Comment: This article is really helpful: http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/C_chars.html

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not mean that the "ASCII value of 2" is stored. It simply stores the small integer 2.

To store the integer that encodes the character `2` in the target character encoding, use `char a = '2';`.